# Interpolation Errors, plot function does not generate proper lines when running

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I am trying to get a graph made for my interpolation program (basically it takes a test function and creates lines utilizing an `interpolation method`)

```
clear all;
close all; 
clc;

x1= [-1 0.75 -0.5 -0.25 0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1];
x2=-1:1001:1;

y1=1./(1+25.*x1.^2);
y2=1./(1+25.*x2.^2);
figure(777)
title('Figure 777')
for loop=1:1:6

    subplot(6,2,loop);
    plot(x2,y2,'linewidth',2);
    hold on
    plot(x1,y1,'r.','markersize',25);
    hold on
end
%%%(A)
[p1,s1,u1] = polyfit(x1,y1,4);
Y1=polyval(p1, x2, s1, u1);
subplot (6,2,1)
plot(x2,Y1,'b','linewidth',6);

%%%(B)
[p2, s2, u2] = polyfit(x1,y1,8);
Y2 = polyval(p2, x2, s2, u2);
subplot(6,2,1)
plot(x2,Y2, 'b', 'linewidth', 6);

%%%(C)
Y3 = interp1(x1, y1, x2, 'linear');
subplot(6,3,1)
plot(x2, Y3, 'b', 'linewidth', 6);

%%%(D)
Y4 = interp1(x1,y1,x2, 'nearest');
subplot(6,4,1)
plot(x2, Y4, 'b', 'linewidth', 6);

%%%(E)
Y5 = interp1(x1,y1,x2, 'spline');
subplot(6,5,1)
plot(x2, Y5, 'b', 'linewidth', 6);

%%%(F)%%%(This method does not exist for Matlab R2017a)
Y6 = interp1(x1,y1,x2, 'makima');
subplot(6,6,1)
plot(x2, Y6, 'b', 'linewidth', 6);
```

**However, none of the lines appear when I run the program. Only the dots. Furthermore I receive these errors:**

> Warning: Polynomial is badly conditioned. Add points with distinct X values or
>   reduce the degree of the polynomial. 
>   In `polyfit (line 73)`
>     In `HwSixTwo (line 27)`
>
> Error using `griddedInterpolant`
>   The grid vectors must contain unique points.
>
> Error in interp1 (line 149)
>   `F = griddedInterpolant(X,V,method);`
>
> Error in HwSixTwo (line 33)
>   `Y3 = interp1(x1, y1, x2, 'linear');`

Comment: Did you look at the contents of `x2`? Does it match your expectation? I bet it doesn't. Also note that you are missing a minus sign in `x1`, which is what causes the error (the x values must be monotonic for `interp1`).

Answer (score 3):

Well one bug that would certainly not generate intended results is here:

```
x2=-1:1001:1;
```

I'm assuming it's your intent to create 1001 points evenly spaced between -1 to 1.  This code is **not** doing this.  The middle number specifies what the spacing is in between successive numbers.  1001 does not make sense which generates only one value which is -1.

Replace your code with the `linspace` function:

```
x2 = linspace(-1, 1, 1001);
```

Also, you're missing a minus sign in one of your values in `x1` - the 0.75:

```
x1= [-1 -0.75 -0.5 -0.25 0 0.25 0.5 0.75 1];
    %    ^^^
```

As Cris noted, your `x` values must be **monotonic** or increasing / decreasing in one direction.